# $|f(z)=(z+1)^2|$ on a triangular region find max min

Tags: complex-analysis

consider function $f(z)=(z+1)^2$ and closed triangular region $R$ with vertices at $z=0,z=2,z=i$

find points in R where $f(z)$ has its max and min

suggestion [intepret |f(z)| as a square of distance betweee $z$ and $-1$]

ans $z=2,z=0$

---

THeorem (help?)

f is continous on a closed bouned region R and that it is analytic and not constant of interior R then max values |f(z)| occurs somewhere in the boundery

---

by lookin at it the closest point from -1 is 0. not sure how  much more to say. and by looking at the where $-1$ is and triangular region $2$ is the furthest so it must be the max.THis is not however a  mathematical argument not where to go from there or if that is enough. would like to make it better

Comment: Finding a maximum for $f(z)$ doesn't make sense. Please edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That theorem is known by *Maximum Modulus Principle*, but you don't need it here. Following the hint you have that
$$|f(z)|=|z+1|^2=dist(z,-1)^2.$$
This tells you that the minimum of $f$ is attained at the point in the triangle that is nearest to $-1$, and that the maximum is attained at the point in the triangle which is fartest from $-1$. After drawing a picture I trust you'll find that these are $0$ and $2$.